Can function call with variable number of parameters be implemented without templates to isolate in C++ file?
I want the executor template in the code below to be put is an isolated C++ file in order to reduce compile time and improve insulation.
It works just fine as a template, but I can’t see a simple way to handle functions with different signatures without template implementation.
Is it doable somehow with std::mem_fn, std::function, std::bind, etc.? I feel there should be a simple packing way, but can’t see it.
#include <functional>
#include <iostream>

struct Point {
    int x=0, y=0;
};

struct Renderable
{
    virtual void OnMouseMove([[maybe_unused]] const Point& pt) 
    { std::cout << "OnMouseMove" << std::endl; }
    virtual void OnMouseWheel([[maybe_unused]] const Point& pt, [[maybe_unused]] int zDelta, [[maybe_unused]] int fwKeys) 
    { std::cout << "OnMouseWheel" << std::endl; }
};

void executor(auto fn, const Point& pt, auto ...args)
{
    /* Some internal logic to handle many renderable objects */

    Renderable renderable;
    fn(renderable, pt, args...);
}

int main()
{
    Point pt;

    auto fn1 = std::mem_fn(&Renderable::OnMouseMove);
    auto fn2 = std::mem_fn(&Renderable::OnMouseWheel);

    executor(fn1, pt);
    executor(fn2, pt, 0, 0);
}


overloads that internally call the template?

@Oersted, it would have worked if I knew the type of the fn*. Per mem_fn: "std::mem_fn returns a call wrapper fn of unspecified type" and the type is hard. So, naive attempt to implement this fails. I guess I can play somehow with argument_type and other members of a call wrapper, but this could be complicated.

Can you change all your member functions to take a single parameter of std::vector<std::any>?

@Eljay std::any is such a pain

@Eljay, thank you. This one should work, but I would like to avoid type erasure and resulting code with casting to get types back. Will keep it as a "plan Omega" in case other options won't work

All of "no type erasure", "no templates", and "variable number of parameters" together won't cut it, I am afraid. You have to remove at least one of these constraints.

@j6t, I am not sure. The approach suggested by *
Oersted* works just fine, just need to way to get the type of function while passing it to the wrapper. The clue is that I never said "unknown number of parameters", with "variable number of parameters" overloading works.

std::mem_fn is a function template, you'll need decltype to extract the type when it is applied to some class member function pointers. Also, have you tried explicit instantiation? I personally think it's cleaner than writing extra overloads.

@KirisameIgna, why would I need decltype? My code above works just fine without it. Can you, please, show a situation where I would need to? Not sure about the approach with explicit instantiation, I already have objects, I don't need to instantiate them. Can you please show what you mean, let's say, on https://godbolt.org?

@DamirTenishev, take your failed attempt as an example, you can rewrite it with decltypeed arguments, the wrapper just compiles. By "explicit instantiation" I mean the explicit instantiation of the function template executor, which allows you to separate the implementation in dedicated files without writing too much thing.
